# Does a wizard ever lose spells they do not cast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, wizard

If a wizard prepares spells in the morning and does not cast any over the course of a day does he lose them when he sleeps that night? Also, is there any upper limit on that time if a wizard doesn't lose those spells? Could an elf wizard for example prepare *color spray* and the sit on it for the next 200 years and then cast it with no problem?

Comment: Are you interested only in losing spells *naturally* as the main text of your question implies, or are [any mechanisms for losing spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spellsteal) of interest?

Comment: Was specifically looking to see if a wizard ever loses spells he prepares naturally, not via external factors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[From the SRD on preparing Wizard spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Preparing-Wizard-Spells)

> Until he prepares spells from his spellbook, the only spells a wizard has available to cast are the ones that he already had prepared from the previous day and has not yet used. During the study period, he chooses which spells to prepare. If a wizard already has spells prepared (from the previous day) that he has not cast, she can abandon some or all of them to make room for new spells.

This states that you don't automatically lose them while sleeping, you can carry over spells from the previous day and opt not to replace them with anything.

Additionally, under "Spell retention" it also says:

> Once a wizard prepares a spell, it remains in his mind as a nearly cast spell until he uses the prescribed components to complete and trigger it or until he abandons it. Certain other events, such as the effects of magic items or special attacks from monsters, can wipe a prepared spell from a character's mind.

So no, you don't lose the spell and you can sit on it for years if you like, but you won't be able to prepare anything else in that spellslot while doing so.

There is nothing mentioned about decay in the PHB, so I don't see anything that would stop you from sitting on one for 200 years, but check with your DM as this seems like something that's more of a campaign or plot detail than a situation the game expects players to be in.

Comment: Could this be interpreted to mean that it stays prepared for 2 days (the day you prepared it and the day after) because of the "*spells prepared (from the previous day)*" since it implies that the spell in mention was actually prepared the previous day?

Comment: @Charanor it might be interpreted like that. But there's a bit more in the SRD that shows they don't, I'll add that in.